# Power Inverter Weird Output

Tags: power, power-electronics, ltspice, simulation, inverter

I'm simulating a power inverter using Analog Devices LT1158IN#PBF as half bridge driver. This is the circuit I'm simulating:
[image: ltspice circuit simulation]
Here is the plot of R1 and V9:
[image: plot r1 and v9]
Seems like the voltage spikes over 20V keeping current low for a certain time period and then current spikes while keeping the voltage to VIN. The desired behavior should be the latter (12VAC fixed). Any Idea why this is happening? I suppose it could be something related to the filter.

**Update:**
This is how the output of the filter looks when removing R5 and measuring the voltage over the LC filter:
[image: lc filters output]

Comment: Did you measure the circuits individually? Try removing R5 and loading them individually and measure the outputs. See if a similar thing happens.

Comment: Just added the plot of the LC filters when R5 is removed. It does look quite weird.

Comment: Do your inductors have any ESR defined?

Comment: They didn't. Now they do. I think the issue was the high current sense resistor not allowing for the inrush current of the capacitor and thus shutting off the bridge driver for a brief period of time.